# How to make a non-active window also react to mouse clicks immediately, rather than having it become only active?

Tags: macos, mac, window, selection, mouse-click

I've been using a Mac at work for a couple of months now, but after getting used to it there still are some annoyances that I'm trying to eliminate. If I have multiple windows open, clicking on a non-active window will activate it - but the application does not register the click. Coming from a Windows background, this makes the UI feel very sluggish, as I feel I'm spending far more clicks than I should.

Is there a way to configure this behavior? I know there are utilities available for Windows to tweak things like this, are there any similar tools available for Mac OS?

Comment: This feature is known as xmouse - I searched for it actively a while back and kept reading that OS-X is basically unable to support it.  I'd love to find out otherwise!  Curiously enough, most windows will receive / honor scroll events even when they're not front-most; just not click events.

Answer (score 1):

What application specifically? I tested with both Safari and Finder and found that clicks in an inactive window will both focus the window as well as activate a click event.

Comment: Now that you mention it, some apps do indeed receive click events (Finder, Terminal). Most other apps don't: XCode, Firefox, TextWrangler, Thunderbird, iChat...

Comment: The “click through” behavior is definitely under the control of individual applications (individual “views”, actually). See [`-acceptsFirstMouse:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/acceptsFirstMouse:) in `NSView` (one of the fundamental base Cocoa UI classes).

Comment: Thanks for the info, Chris. So much for consistency, but oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you ask, but you can try [Zooom/2](http://www.coderage-software.com/zooom/index.html) — one of its features is brining windows to front on hover after customizable time and that is just one of many features.

Also not excactly what you are asking: holding ⌘ and clicking background windows will fire click event without activating window.

Comment: Indeed, not really what I was looking for. The ⌘+click 'trick' either doesn't work for me or it's also application-specific, like normal clicks. Strangely enough, some clicks are always honored (specifically buttons like the close, minimize and maximize ones), regardless of what application I'm dealing with...

Comment: As Chris Johnsen said, there is an option to ignore such clicks, but I think that this could not be changed for system provided buttons like close, minimize and maximize

Comment: Option + Click does work for me (on Chrome at least) -- it brings a non-active to foreground and fires the click event.

Answer (score 0):

Find NSView.h through spotlight. Search for acceptsFirstMouse , edit the statement to:
 `(BOOL)acceptsFirstMouse:(NSEvent *)event;`

Comment: What exactly are you suggesting here? This doesn't look like something an average user can or should do.